# Is it safe to `rm` folders from the .Trashes folder on an external drive?

Tags: terminal, finder, trash

I trashed some folders from an external drive using the finder. They are now in that drives `.Trashes` folder. When I right click them in the trash (aka Finder) and select "Delete Immediately..." it takes forever, so I was thinking to use the terminal command `rm -rf` on them to get rid of them. Is that going to cause problems?

Comment: No, it’s fine. Speed-wise there may be no benefit though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually do this a lot, especially if there is a huge number of files and folders in the trash. Works like a charm, and in case you empty all trash folders Finder will even update the icon to show an empty trash bin again afterwards.